# Swing Repeated repaints JComboBox flicker

Tags: java, swing, animation, repaint

I'm having trouble with my animations and my JComboBox. In my application, I can move and transform my shapes either by using the mouse and keyboard or by setting animations.

My component hierarchy is as follows : a JPanel placed in my JFrame contains a panel called EditorCanvas where shapes are modified and drawn, and a panel called DrawMenu containing some JButtons and my JComboBox.

JFrame -> JPanel -> EditorCanvas
JFrame -> JPanel -> DrawMenu      -> JComboBox

The JComboBox is used to choose a shape to be added to the canvas on a click.
In another thread I call repaint() on my canvas every 10ms after having computed the new positions, etc...

The problem is that I cannot use my JComboBox anymore, as the popup disappear immediately after I open it. And this is caused at some point by my repaints. The thing that is really weird is that my JComboBox is placed in another panel, so it should not be repainted.

I tried to replace my repaint calls in a Runnable called by SwingUtilities.invokeLater, but the problem remained the same.

Here are some relevant parts of my code :

```
public class EditorCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        // To keep keyboard focus
        this.requestFocusInWindow();

        this.graphics = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        this.graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        this.mainRenderer.paintAll(this.graphics);
    }


public class AnimationManager implements Runnable {

    ...

    public void run () {

        try {

            while (Thread.currentThread() == this.thread) {

                // Update time values
                double curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                double deltaTime = curTime - this.lastTime;
                this.lastTime = curTime;

                for (Animation anim : this.animations) {
                    anim.update(deltaTime);
                }

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public @Override void run() {
                        EditorParameters.getCanvas().repaint();
                    }
                });

                // Pause the animation if it has to
                synchronized (this) {

                    while (this.pause) {
                        System.out.println("\nAnimation paused!\n");
                        this.wait();
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            }
```

Comment: Try `validate/revalidate/invalidate` in place of `repaint`. I can't say will it work or not because you have not shared a complete testable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I cannot use my JComboBox anymore, as the popup disappear immediately

Painting method are for painting only.

```
this.requestFocusInWindow();
```

You should never invoke a method like that in a painting method.

I don't even know why you need a custom panel. You should NOT be invoking the `paintAll()` method of another component. Swing will look after painting all the child components of a panel.

Comment: In fact I do not want to repaint the JComboBox or other, it just get repainted when I repaint the EditorCanvas. It's definitely not what I want, but I cannot help it : it not only repaints my EditorCanvas, but also other panels, I think.

Comment: And for the other remarks : I called requestFocusInWindow() because I often lose the keyboard focus without understanding it. paintAll is the method in another class that paint the shapes on the panel, I just discovered that this method name already existed in some Swing predefined classes.

Comment: @user3501153, `because I often lose the keyboard focus` - of course you lose keyboard focus when you click on the combo box. It is NOT the solution to invoke the requestFocusInWindow() method in the paintComponent() method. The solution is to not use a KeyListener but instead to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). If you need further help then you need to post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: While trying to create a SSSCE and reducing the code to the strict minimum, I found it was my call of requestFocusInWindow() that was stoling focus from the JComboBox... As you said. But I still have a problem of focus : the canvas does not have it at all. And I need it to allow my mouse and keyboard listeners to work.

Comment: Thank you camickr. I spent about a week on this, because my application is rather big... So it was not the repaint in itself. Are you sure key bindings are the only way to do this? Whatever, one more time I thank you. =)

Comment: `I found it was my call of requestFocusInWindow() that was stoling focus from the JComboBox` - that was the point of my comment and why I told you to remove it. `I spent about a week on this` Why did it take you a day to remove a single line of code from your program to test it? Why ask a question if you don't listen to the suggestions? `Are you sure key bindings are the only way to do this?` - there are always many ways to do something. I suggest what I think is the best way (search the forum if you don't belive me). Again, why do I have to repeat myself?